# type checking constexpr function to check non-template type or template type on C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, type-traits

I wrote type checking constexpr function.
It the type is `type1` or `type2` then returns true, otherwise returns false.

Here is the code. It works as I expected.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

struct type1{};
struct type2{};
struct type3{};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_type1or2() {
    return std::is_same_v<T, type1> || std::is_same_v<T, type2>;
}

static_assert(is_type1or2<type1>());
static_assert(is_type1or2<type2>());
static_assert(!is_type1or2<type3>());

int main(){}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/dncKo1Pbb

Now, `type1` is changed to template that has non-type parameter.
How to do the same type checking?

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t N>
struct type1{};
struct type2{};
struct type3{};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_type1or2() {
    return std::is_same_v<T, type2>;
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr bool is_type1or2() {
    return std::is_same_v<T, type1<N>>;
}

// I want to write as follows but I couldn't find a way, so far.
// static_assert(is_type1or2<type1<42>>());
// so I pass explicit second template argument 42.
static_assert(is_type1or2<type1<42>, 42>());

static_assert(is_type1or2<type2>());
static_assert(!is_type1or2<type3>());

int main(){}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/G1o5447z8

I tried but I can't eliminate the second template argument. It avoids generic code.
Is there any good way to check the type is `type1<anyN>` or `type2` ?

In my actual case, I have 20 of non template types like `type2` and 20 of template types like `type1`. And half of them need to match. I want to avoid code repeatation as long as I can.

### Clarify requirement

For template type `type1<N>`, `N` is not important. Both template is `type1` is important. So the result of `is_type1or2<type1<10>>()` and `is_type1or2<type1<20>>()` are always same. I don't need to define individual template argument specialization based matching.

Comment: In my actual usecase, N could be 2 or 4 only. N is a kind of customization point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved easily if you change the syntax of the `static_assert` to accept the type as a function argument, as this will allow function template argument deduction (see [Takatoshi Kondo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1922763)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74208460)).

However, this can also be solved by writing a template that checks whether a type is an instantiation of a template:

```
template<template <std::size_t> typename, typename>
struct is_instance_of : std::false_type {};

template<template <std::size_t> typename T, std::size_t N>
struct is_instance_of<T, T<N>> : std::true_type {};
```

Now `is_instance_of` can be used in the function (without argument deduction) as:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_type1or2() {
    return 
        is_instance_of<type1, T>::value  // repeat for other templates that take a size_t parameter 
        or std::is_same_v<T, type2>;     // repeat for non-template types
}
```

If you have other template types that you want to allow (i.e. templates that take parameters other than a `size_t`), you can edit `is_instance_of` as needed.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Mdf9Yqrbz).

Comment: That still requires to instantiate `type1` (you can't do `is_type1or2<type1>()`).

Comment: @Nelfeal Yes, that's true. The question doesn't indicate that `static_assert(is_type1or2<type1>())` is desired though, the example given is `static_assert(is_type1or2<type1<42>>())`. Also, the OP's self answer doesn't allow for the former either, suggesting that that's not the intent anyway.

Comment: OP's first example does show `static_assert(is_type1or2<type1>())`. Granted there is no mention that it's a requirement, but it's fairly easy to provide.

Comment: @Nelfeal In the OP's first example `type1` is not a template at all. In none of the OP's examples do they indicate that they want to check something like a template, they only appear to want to check concrete types (either regular types, or instantiations of templates). Sure, it may be fairly easy to provide such a check, but I don't want to expand upon a solution that is not asked for, unless there's a good reason to do so (which I can't see here).

Comment: I guess we are interpreting the last paragraph of the question differently.

Comment: @Nelfeal Yes, that appears to be the case. Perhaps the OP will clarify what they mean if they think it's confusing/misleading.

Comment: I tried your answer demo. When I updated type1 .. type3 to decralation only, the demo still works fine. I guess that this approach also don't need instantiation. See https://godbolt.org/z/fPT6x7n19 Am I understanding correctly ?

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo Yes, no instantiation actually happens (or to be precise, the types don't need to be complete, i.e there doesn't need to be a definition of `type1` or `type3` for the solution to work), but my solution will only work for concrete types, i.e. `static_assert(is_type1or2<type1<5>>());` will work, but `static_assert(is_type1or2<type1>());` won't. From your question, I thought that's what you wanted, but now I'm confused given the discussion under your answer.

Comment: Let me clarify the meaning of the last paragraph of my question is I have type1 .. type20 non-template classes and type21 .. type40 of template classes that have std::size_t non-type template argument. And half of them, e.g. type1.. type10 and type21 .. type 30 need to match. match means return true the is_typeXXX() function. Other types return false.

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo Yes, I understand that part. What I'm asking is, for the class templates that have a size_t parameter, do you want to check whether, 1) the class template belongs to the set that needs to match, or 2) an instantiation of the class template belongs to the set that needs to match. In other words, do you want to check if 1) `type1` belongs to the set, or 2) `type1<5>` belongs to the set? (Currently your question asks for (2) but not (1)).

Comment: I understand what part of my question is ambiguous. I expect that both `type1<5>` and `type1<6>` match `is_type1()` . The `std::size_t` template argument could be ignored.

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo In that case, Nelfeal's answer [doesn't work](https://godbolt.org/z/WdW7oE5vK) (I've added `static_assert(is_type1or2<type1<5>>());` to that demo and it doesn't compile). So I'm confused by your comments to Nelfeal that their solution works for your case.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own type trait:

```
template <typename>
struct is_type1 : public std::false_type {};

template <std::size_t N>
struct is_type1<type1<N>> : public std::true_type {};
```

This still requires the usage to instantiate an actual type:

```
static_assert(is_type1or2<type1<42>>());
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GGfzhh4qv)

You can also do it this way:

```
template <template<std::size_t> class>
struct is_type1 : public std::false_type {};

template <>
struct is_type1<type1> : public std::true_type {};
```

But then `is_type1` can only be instantiated with templates that have a `std::size_t` parameter. So you can no longer do `is_type1<T>::value || std::is_same_v<T, type2>` because `is_type1` only accepts templates while `std::is_same_v` only accepts types, and `T` cannot be both. It can work if `type2` is also defined like `type1`, that is:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct type1{};
template <std::size_t N>
struct type2{};

template <template<std::size_t> class>
struct is_type1or2_t : public std::false_type {};
template <>
struct is_type1or2_t<type1> : public std::true_type {};
template <>
struct is_type1or2_t<type2> : public std::true_type {};

template <template<std::size_t> class T>
constexpr bool is_type1or2() {
    return is_type1or2_t<T>::value;
}
```

But you still can't use `is_type1or2` with `type3`, even in a `static_assert`. So you also need to add an overload for simple types:

```
template <typename>
constexpr bool is_type1or2() {
    return false;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ys93YMavc)

If you also need an instantiation of `type1` or `type2` to match, you can add yet another type trait:

```
template <typename>
struct is_type1or2_instantiation_t : public std::false_type {};
template <std::size_t N>
struct is_type1or2_instantiation_t<type1<N>> : public std::true_type {};
template <std::size_t N>
struct is_type1or2_instantiation_t<type2<N>> : public std::true_type {};
// [...]
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_type1or2() {
    return is_type1or2_instantiation_t<T>::value;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/f88dhrdb5)

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for what the OP explicitly asks for https://godbolt.org/z/z537bj9cT i.e. `static_assert(is_type1or2<type1<42>>());` doesn't even compile. That's fine if the OP edits their question, but as it stands this solution answers a different (though related) question.

Comment: @cigien Fair enough, I added a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

After some of try and error, I finally found the solution.

> In my actual case, I have 20 of non template types like type2 and 20 of template types like type1. And half of them need to match. I want to avoid code repeatation as long as I can.

In order to demonstrate my situation above, I added `type4` non-type template similar to `type1`. And `type1`, `type2` and `type4` need to match.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t N>
struct type1{};
struct type2{};
struct type3{};
template <std::size_t N> // type4 added
struct type4{};

// overload for non-templates
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_type1or2or4(T) { // or 4 added
    return std::is_same_v<T, type2>;
}

// overload for templates
template <template <std::size_t> typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr bool is_type1or2or4(T<N>) { // or 4 added
    return 
        std::is_same_v<T<N>, type1<N>> ||
        std::is_same_v<T<N>, type4<N>>;
}

static_assert(is_type1or2or4(type1<42>()));
static_assert(is_type1or2or4(type2()));
static_assert(!is_type1or2or4(type3()));
static_assert(is_type1or2or4(type4<12>()));

int main(){}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/17GbGK738

I use template argument deduction. Then I can extract N and pass it as template argument.
There are two overload funtion templates. One of for non-template types, the other is template types.
It works fine.

Comment: You don't need to instantiate `type1` or `type4`. See my answer.

Comment: Based on your answer (1st Demo), I added type4. https://godbolt.org/z/e14hK68z9 . It seems that I need to add is_typeN for all template types that I want to match. On 2nd demo, as you mentioned, if type2 is non template as my original example, it doesn't work. I didn't memtioned that in my actural usecase, instantiation is not a problem. Sorry for the mixup. I think that my approach can reduce code repeatation compate to the 1st demo of your approach So I use my answser approach this time.  But your 2nd approach that eliminates instantiation is nice!

Comment: You might not have seen my last edit. All you need to make `type2` work is an additional overload. There, instead of just `return false`, you can do `return std::is_same_v<T, type2>` just like in your answer.

Comment: Thanks! I understand. Your 2nd apprach works fine without instantiation for both template and non-template.

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo It sounds like you're fine with checking for templates instead of actual instantiations, i.e. you want to be able to do things like `static_assert(is_type1or2<type1>())` (where `type1` is a template)? I'm not sure how that would be a useful check to perform, but nonetheless, could you edit your question to include that requirement? It does change the question substantially if that's part of your requirement.

Comment: Yes. I will do later. Please give me a time to consider sentence. Anyway, I think that your `is_instance_of` approach satisfies my requirement perfectly :)